# Mousewheel navigation through page blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, mouseevent, mousewheel

For instance I have a page of 5 blocks:

[image]

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>
<div class="div5"></div>
```

Each block is 100% width and height of a window, the red one(1) is visible.

```
.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4, .div5 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I want to navigate throgh those blocks using mouse wheel. When i scroll down the second block animates from bottom, a little more down the third one animates. And I don't want scroll bar to be visible.

I know I should use jquery mousewheel plugin and choose an action depends on delta. But don't see the whole situation.

I hope my question is clear. Would appreciate any help and websites who already implemented such kind of naviation to dig in it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using jquery scroll event as shown [here](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

```
$('#target').scroll(function() {
//code goes here
})
```

also you can hide scrollbar as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshMesser/VUSuZ/)

or you can try infinite scroll plugins.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, each of your blocks should have "position: fixed". The first block would have top: 0px; bottom 0px; left 0px; right 0px; While for the block below that, left and right are still 0, but top and bottom are now offset by the height of your window (you can get the height of your window with $(window).innerHeight(); And so on and so forth with the other blocks.

Then whenever the user is scrolling (using the scroll events already given in other answers) you simply modify the top and bottom (equally) of all your blocks by however much you want each time the event fires.

Cheers